# A Compact-Closed Topology

Tags: general-topology

Given a set $X$, Is there any topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that given any $Y \subseteq X$ it satisfies the following property

$$ Y\text{ is closed if and only if }Y\text{ is compact }$$

I am confused with this because I am supposed to find a topology with some restrictions. I was able to conclude that $\tau_f \subset \tau$ where $\tau_f$ denotes the co-finite topology on X.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It suffices to show that on any set $X$ there is a topology $\tau$ that makes $X$ a compact Hausdorff space: every closed subset of a compact spaces is compact, and every compact subset of a compact Hausdorff space is closed. If $X$ is finite, this is very easy to do. If $X$ is infinite, topologize it as the one-point compactification of a space similar to the finite examples.